# Is there a VB function to convert 32 bit float to little endian hex

Tags: vba, floating-point, type-conversion, hex, endianness

As shown here: [https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/)
I need to convert a 32 bit float to a little endian hex (click the swap endiness button before converting). I've managed to do this in python by converting to big endian then reordering, but I have no idea how to approach this issue in VB as I'm entirely new to the language. Using the Hex inbuilt function returns 19a, which i assume means its not correctly evaluating my input as a single.

I've found a recommended solution here but cant get it working:
https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6404

Any suggestions would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want the [hexadecimal representation of the four bytes comprising the `Single`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31506928/11683)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this - the most obvious being the Copy Memory API. Some time ago, a pretty neat solution was published here: [Extracting bits from a float in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431346/extracting-bits-from-a-float-in-vba) which avoided the need for the API

Basically, you'd just need a couple of short functions:

```
Option Explicit

Type SingleType
  Value As Single
End Type
Type FourBytesType
  Value(3) As Byte
End Type

Private Function SingleToBytes(f As Single) As Variant
    Dim sngType As SingleType
    Dim bytesType As FourBytesType
    
    sngType.Value = f
    LSet bytesType = sngType
    SingleToBytes = bytesType.Value
End Function

Private Function BytesToHex(bytes As Variant) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(bytes) To UBound(bytes)
        result = result & IIf(bytes(i) < 16, "0", "") & Hex(bytes(i))
    Next
    BytesToHex = result
    
End Function
```

If you wanted to test Endianness and reverse the array, then something like the following, which kind of uses a Byte Order Mark, could be added. I haven't tested it on a big-endian processor but I think it'd work:

```
Private Function IsLittleEndianProcessor() As Boolean
    Const BOM As Single = 1
    Const MSB As Byte = 63
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim n As Long
    
    bytes = SingleToBytes(BOM)
    n = UBound(bytes)
    IsLittleEndianProcessor = (bytes(n) = MSB)
    
End Function

Private Function ChangeEndianness(bytes As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result() As Byte
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    
    ReDim result(UBound(bytes))
    m = UBound(bytes)
    For n = LBound(bytes) To UBound(bytes)
        result(m) = bytes(n)
        m = m - 1
    Next
    
    ChangeEndianness = result
End Function
```

I'm not actually sure how you want the hex string displayed but you could step backwards through the array to write the hex if needed. Sample test would be:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim bytes As Variant
    Dim output As String
    
    bytes = SingleToBytes(3.1415)
    
    If Not IsLittleEndianProcessor Then
        bytes = ChangeEndianness(bytes)
    End If
    output = BytesToHex(bytes)
    Debug.Print output
    
End Sub
```